# Hibernate AttributeOverride annotation error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have following entities:

```
public class MyEntity extends AuditableEntity {
    @Column
    private String name;
}
```

`AuditableEntity` class:

```
public class AuditableEntity {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid-gen", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid-gen", strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;

    @CreatedBy
    @JsonIgnore
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "user", column = @Column(name = "created_by_id")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "clientId", column = @Column(name = "created_by_client_id"))
    })
    private AuditorDetails createdBy;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @JsonIgnore
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "user", column = @Column(name = "last_modified_by_id")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "clientId", column = @Column(name = "last_modified_by_client_id"))
    })
    private AuditorDetails lastModifiedBy;

}
```

And my `AuditorDetails` class:

```
@Embeddable
public class AuditorDetails {

    @Column(name = "auditor_client_id")
    private String clientId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn
    private User user;
}
```

Also, I have `AuditorAware` that returns `AuditorDetails` object. When I try to run this, I have following exception:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity:
>   com.aaa.MyEntity column: user_id (should be mapped with insert="false"
>   update="false")

But I can't make this column(s) not updatable and not insertable. The main goal is to have in `MyEntity` 4 columns - `created_by_id`, `created_by_client_id`, `last_modified_by_id`, `last_modified_by_client_id` that will contain all data about row modification and creation. How to fix this exception?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue just adding annotations `AssociationOverrides`:

```
@CreatedBy
@JsonIgnore
@Embedded
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "user", joinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "created_by_id"))
})
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "user", column = @Column(name = "created_by_id")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "clientId", column = @Column(name = "created_by_client_id"))
})
private AuditorDetails createdBy;

@LastModifiedBy
@JsonIgnore
@Embedded
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "user", joinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "last_modified_by_id"))
})
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "user", column = @Column(name = "last_modified_by_id")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "clientId", column = @Column(name = "last_modified_by_client_id"))
})
private AuditorDetails lastModifiedBy;
```